# ¿Cómo modificar mi ORM para mostrar la fecha en el select?

Tags: python, django

Tengo un registro de datos y en cada uno de los registros se guarda una fecha, luego necesito mostrar la información en dependencia de la fecha en que se guardó. Al ver los datos de las fechas en mi `select` se visualizan de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de mi `forms` donde creo el `select`. Imagino que la respuesta a mi problema está en modificar el ORM (el cual he intentado de varias formas y no lo logro) y los datos deben ser `distinct` para que no se repita el mes.

```
class Report2Form(Form):
    reporteFecha = ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=ConsumoElect.objects.values_list('fecha', flat=True), 
        widget=Select(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            # ('F , Y') de esta forma es que me aparece como ´abril, 2023´
        }),
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realicé la misma pregunta en la comunidad de idioma inglés y me dieron la siguiente respuesta la cual funciona perfectamente, solo es modificar el `form`:

```py
 class Report2Form(Form): 
    
    fecha = ChoiceField(    
        choices = [],          
        widget=Select(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
        }),
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['fecha'].choices = [('','------------')] + [(f"{d:%Y-%m}", f"{d:%B, %Y}") for d in ConsumoElect.objects.dates("fecha", "month")]
```